# loading nodes with Ajax/jQuery

Tags: theming, 6, javascript, ajax

Assume that we have a list of titles on the left and a div on the right side of the page that displays posts. when I click one of the titles it first removes content of that div and then loads node content. how can I do this? is there any module or function to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the [Quick Tabs](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs/) and [Vertical Tabs](http://drupal.org/project/vertical_tabs) modules.  Otherwise you could write your own custom module if you had super specific needs and are proficient with drupal menu callbacks and php and of course jQuery.